# How c++ or compiler version are changing the output?

Tags: c++, variables, operators, variable-assignment

**using 16 bit compiler e.g turbo c++**

```
int a = 10; 
cout << a << a++ << ++a;
```

Output
**121111**

**When using 32/64 bit compiler or any online compiler**

Output: 101012

Why this is happening I'm aware about associativity and precedence is it due to the **compiler version** or **c++ version** ?

Comment: (The short version of Taekahn's link is that the execution of operand expression for most binaries operation, beside logical ones, is *undefined* -- that is, left for the implementation to decide, and thus can vary *from compiler to compiler* or even from a version to another.)

Comment: Don't waste your time on Turbo C++. It is obsolete (has been for more than ~25 years) and pre-standard - noone use it anymore. You will just learn bad habits and obsolete techniques. Invest your time in learning modern C++ instead.

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- while that's true (although a bit annoying to those of us who developed Turbo C++ <g>), the problem in the question doesn't come from using an old compiler.

Comment: Is it due to the c++ versions ?